# Fire is unaffected by any force field

Tags: force-fields, fire

No matter what I do, no matter what render engine, no matter the strength and flow of the force field, I cannot get any fire/gas simulation to ever be moved by a force (specifically wind). I've created new projects, I've tried tons of settings and followed many tutorials, I've tried different versions of Blender, but I feel like this is being caused by some random setting I haven't found. Please help, my animation project is dead in the water if I can't figure this out.

[Link to .blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GoGItfl9vegRINMjZunVwANYwuPnBXuN/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, comedically, I solved it. The problem was the option "Flame Smoke" under the Fire tab in the domain. It cannot be zero, or else the fire will not be affected by forces. This seems very silly to me, but I hope this might be able to help someone someday.

Comment: Welcome to the world of arcane 3d modeling software!   pull some hair out, throw salt over your shoulder, waste a whole afternoon on a tiny issue.... !